# Gomega ghttp returns 500 status code

Tags: go, ginkgo, gomega

I've written some tests in Go using Ginkgo/Gomega, but no matter what I do, `ghttp` returns a 500 status to my client with no content. Here is some sample code:

```
var _ = Describe("Client", func() {

    var (
        server *ghttp.Server
    )

    BeforeEach(func() {
        server = ghttp.NewServer()
        server.AllowUnhandledRequests = false
        server.Writer = GinkgoWriter
    })

    AfterEach(func() {
        server.Close()
    })

    Describe("fetching a node list", func() {

        BeforeEach(func() {

            server.AppendHandlers(
                ghttp.CombineHandlers(
                    ghttp.VerifyRequest("GET", "/nodes"),
                    ghttp.RespondWith(204, ""),
                ),
            )
        })

        It("should be able to fetch a node list", func() {
            response, err := myclient.Get(NODES)
            Ω(err).ShouldNot(HaveOccurred())
            Ω(response).ShouldNot(BeNil(), "No response was returned from nodes.")

            data, err := httputil.DumpResponse(response, true)
            Ω(err).ShouldNot(HaveOccurred())
            GinkgoWriter.Write(data)

            Ω(response.StatusCode).Should(Equal(204))
        })

    })

})
```

According to the Gomega [changelog](https://github.com/onsi/gomega/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> If a registered handler makes a failing assertion ghttp will return 500.
>
> If a registered handler panics, ghttp will return 500 and fail the test.

However, I can't get these tests to fail, even if I post to a different route, remove the append handlers call, etc. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the OP figured it out as this is way late to the game. I had the same issue so sharing for anyone else that comes across it.

In my case, my **It** function was outside the **Context** function but you won't get any errors at compile time.  Inside the nested **Describe** You want a structure like:

```
Describe
  Context
    BeforeEach
    It
```

Note where the BeforeEach and the It are contained within the Context.

Hope this helps someone.